# (Java + Kotlin) Autowiring: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have a class(Java) and I tried autowire a Kotlin class :
Kotlin class:

```
@Component
class HelloWorld {

    fun test() {
        println("")
    }
}
```

java :
`@Autowired
    private HelloWorld hello;`

> Error:  Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean found for dependency [teste.payroll.HelloWorld]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.fact

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte, that is Kotlin, not javascript

Comment: Is this a spring boot app using maven? If so, please post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Are you sure that your bean is being discovered? So in which package is your main and where is this class? `AutoDiscovery` on?